# SpringBoot : Altering Column length

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my `MySQl` table, I want to change the length of my column from `varchar(2)` to `varchar(10)`. I am using docker as my database server.

I tried using `columnDefinition` but in my table `desc` I still see the old Type `varchar(2)`.
This is the command I added to my `Entity Class` :

```
@Column(name = "CHAPTER_CODE", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "varchar(10)")
private String chapterCode;
```

And then I bootRun the server. Since I am new to SpringBoot, so is there something which I missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `length`

> (Optional) The column length. (Applies only if a
>   string-valued column is used.) By default it is 255

so you should simply add

```
@Column(name = "CHAPTER_CODE", nullable = false,  length = 10)
private String chapterCode;
```

Comment: Does this change get automatically applied to the database when you use: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update    ?

Comment: @Stradosphere yes, it should be.

Comment: Tried changing the length but it didn't affect my database.